# How do I write a Semantic UI radio group in React using the State Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-group

I am trying to write a radio button group using Semantic UI in React. I can get the Radio Group example on the [Radio page](https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/radio/) of the Semantic UI to work. It is written by extending `Component`. I want to write the same thing defining React components as functions instead of classes and using the [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). I can't get this to work.

I modified the example to look like this.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Form, Radio} from 'semantic-ui-react'


export const RadioExampleRadioGroup = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState({});
    const handleChange = event => setValue({value: event.target.value});

    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Field>
                Selected value: <b>{value.value}</b>
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
                <Radio
                    label='Choose this'
                    name='radioGroup'
                    value='this'
                    checked={value.value === 'this'}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
                <Radio
                    label='Or that'
                    name='radioGroup'
                    value='that'
                    checked={value.value === 'that'}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </Form.Field>
        </Form>
    )
};
```

Nothing happens in the UI when I click on the radio buttons.

Running in the debugger I see that `handleChange` is getting called and appears to be doing the right thing, but it looks like `undefined` is passed to the `checked` functions.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Making it onClick solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried Semantic UI on Codesandbox and found that `event.target.value` - is undefined, because `target` - is a `label` element, not `input`, so you need to change

```
const handleChange = event => setValue({value: event.target.value});
```

to

```
const handleChange = (event, {value}) => setValue({ value });
```

like documentation of Semantic UI [says](https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/radio/#types-radio-group)

And one more advice. If you need to store just one radio button value, you don't need to store it in the object, so you could rewrite your code to:

```
export const RadioExampleRadioGroup = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    const handleChange = (event, {value}) => setValue(value);

    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Field>
                Selected value: <b>{value}</b>
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
                <Radio
                    label='Choose this'
                    name='radioGroup'
                    value='this'
                    checked={value === 'this'}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
                <Radio
                    label='Or that'
                    name='radioGroup'
                    value='that'
                    checked={value === 'that'}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </Form.Field>
        </Form>
    )
};
```