# Radio button checked property not called from Button in a List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, semantic-ui, radio-group

I want to write a React component that presents the user with a list of proposals they can either accept or reject using a radio button from [Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/).

[image: desired component]

My app looks like this.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {Proposals} from "./components/Proposals";

function App() {
    const proposals = [
        {id: "1", context: "The cat is happy."},
        {id: "2", context: "The triangle is blue."}
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            <Proposals proposals={proposals}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

My Proposals component looks like this.

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import {Form, Header, List, Radio} from "semantic-ui-react";

export const Proposals = ({proposals}) => {
    const [judgments, setJudgments] = useState(
        proposals.reduce((result, proposal) => {
            result[proposal.id] = {accept: false, reject: false};
            return result;
        }, {})
    );

    const judge = (id) => {
        return function (e, {value}) {
            judgments[id].accept = value === "accept";
            judgments[id].reject = value === "reject";
            setJudgments(judgments)
        };
    };

    return (
        <div id="proposals">
            <Header>Proposals</Header>
            <List>
                {proposals.map(proposal => {
                        return (
                            <List.Item key={proposal.id}>
                                <div>{proposal.context}</div>
                                <Form>
                                    <Form.Group inline>
                                        <Radio label="Accept"
                                               value="accept"
                                               name="accept-reject"
                                               checked={judgments[proposal.id].accept}
                                               onChange={judge(proposal.id)}/>
                                        <Radio label="Reject"
                                               value="reject"
                                               name="accept-reject"
                                               checked={judgments[proposal.id].reject}
                                               onChange={judge(proposal.id)}/>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form>
                            </List.Item>
                        )
                    }
                )}
            </List>
        </div>
    )
};
```

The tricky thing I'm doing is writing my `onChange` handler `judge` as a closure so that I can pass in the id of the proposal being operated on. This works. When I click on a radio button, the `judge` function is called, and if I log its values to the console they all look correct.

However, the radio button states do not change when I click on them. If I make the `checked` property call a function that also logs to the console, I see that it only gets called once when the app is loaded and never again.

I use the [same pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58735268/how-do-i-write-a-semantic-ui-radio-group-in-react-using-the-state-hook) with a single radio group and it works fine. Presumably there's something about the radio buttons being inside a list that is messing things up, but I can't figure out what that is.

---

Following the suggestion of the answer below I changed my `judge` function to the following.

```
const judge = (id) => {
    return function (e, {value}) {
        setJudgments(prev => {
            if (prev.id !== id) return prev;
            return {
                ...prev,
                accept: value === "accept",
                reject: value === "reject"
            }
        })
    }
};
```

I have the same problem.

This does appear to be related to my not properly [updating state](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-usestate-in-react-ecb9952e406c/) though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the closure on `judge`. Your problem is that you're mutating the `state`

```
judgments[id].accept = value === "accept"
```

You should set your state using the updater version of `useState` setter.

Like this

```
return function (e, {value}) {
     setJudgments(prev =>({
         ...prev,
         [id] :{
             ...prev[id],
            accept: value === "accept",
            reject: value === "reject"
         }
     }))
};
```

Comment: What is `prev`? When I make the above function the one returned by my `judge` closure I get the error "prev.map is not a function". The same if I replace `prev` with `judgments`.

Comment: `prev` is the `snapshot` of `judgements`. I used `map` cause I assumed that `judgments` is an array but it isn't right? Is an object?

Comment: `judgements` is an object. It will look like this `{"1":{"accept":false,"reject":false},"2":{"accept":false,"reject":false}}`. But see my edit above.

Comment: Updating the answer

Comment: Almost. This does it inside the object update...                [id]: {
                    accept: value === "accept",
                    reject: value === "reject"
                }

Comment: Ops. My mistake There it is. hhaahha